# waypoints execute javascript for animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-waypoints, adobe-edge

I've got a few animations (made with Adobe Edge Animate) on my website connected with the waypoints.js. If the users scrolls to some waypoints the script executes the javascript for the animation like so:

```
var $datenbeschaffung_an = $('.datenbeschaffung');


$datenbeschaffung_an.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') {
         AdobeEdge.loadComposition('animation_beschaffung_151116', 'EDGE-514335', {
    scaleToFit: "both",
    bScaleToParent: "true",
    centerStage: "horizontal",
    minW: "0px",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "870px",
    height: "710px"
}, {"dom":{}}, {"style":{"${symbolSelector}":{"isStage":"true","rect":["undefined","undefined","870px","710px"],"fill":["rgba(255,255,255,1)"]}},"dom":[{"rect":["0","0","870px","710px","auto","auto"],"id":"Poster","fill":["rgba(0,0,0,0)","images/fallback_beschaffung.png","0px","0px"],"type":"image","tag":"img"}]});
  }
}, {
  offset: '20%'
});

$datenbeschaffung_an.waypoint(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'up') {
         AdobeEdge.loadComposition('animation_beschaffung_151116', 'EDGE-514335', {
    scaleToFit: "both",
    bScaleToParent: "true",
    centerStage: "horizontal",
    minW: "0px",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "870px",
    height: "710px"
}, {"dom":{}}, {"style":{"${symbolSelector}":{"isStage":"true","rect":["undefined","undefined","870px","710px"],"fill":["rgba(255,255,255,1)"]}},"dom":[{"rect":["0","0","870px","710px","auto","auto"],"id":"Poster","fill":["rgba(0,0,0,0)","images/fallback_beschaffung.png","0px","0px"],"type":"image","tag":"img"}]});
  }
}, {
  offset: '-2%'
});
```

The script works fine but if the user is scrolling very fast, the animations won't load, because the viewport time is to short to render the complete animation. You can check it out on [here](http://edc.headonline.de)! Test it: Scroll down very fast and then scroll up again: as you can see, the animations aren't loaded completely.

Do you have any solution for it?

Comment: the link you posted is a blank page.

Comment: The link works fine for me, but check it out: http://www.edc.headonline.de